# M.2 NVME SSD No longer detected by motherboard

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, motherboard, bios

I bought a Crucial P1 1TB nvme ssd and installed it on to my motherboard, booted into windows, created new simple volume and copied all my stuff into it, everything's great. I turn off my pc and turn it on the next day and the drive is missing, I thought huh, maybe the connection is lose or something, so I take it out and plug it back in, turned on the computer and the drive is back with all my stuff. Then I turn the pc off and on again and the drive is missing again! I go into bios and there it says no nvme drive detected. What is happening, why is my drive no longer being detected?

I'm on the latest bios version.

My drive order:
1. 250gb ssd (OS)
2. WD 1TB
3. Seagate 2TB
4. nvme ssd

My motherboard: http://download.gigabyte.eu/FileList/Manual/mb_manual_ga-z170-gaming-k3_e.pdf

Also to mention I configured the nvme to gpt if it matters, I think my other drives are mbr.

Comment: Update the firmware which in your case is UEFI, not BIOS.

Comment: Could be a hardware fault on the motherboard or SSD.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia How do I update UEFI?

Comment: Search for it in the manufacturer's website. Please note that some still call it "BIOS".

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I updated the bios using this method: https://i.imgur.com/XI4VOcs.jpg

Comment: The SSD may need a firmware update as well and NVMEs really need OSes in UEFI mode. If you have the OS installed in Legacy mode, as suggested by "my other drives are MBR", that was a mistake.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I've reformatted it to mbr, the issue still persists.

Comment: So you did the exact opposite of what you should and expected it to be different? Again, Legacy and MBR in your case **is a mistake**.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia So what should I do now?

Comment: First you need to understand that you have UEFI, not BIOS, and that for better results/performance you should have the OS installed in UEFI mode (and GPT drive). NVMEs especially need this mode to work if it's the boot drive but even if not it's better to have all in the recommended mode.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia in my UEFI there's a "Storage boot option control" setting which has "legacy", "uefi" and "disabled" options.

Comment: It doesn't matter now unless you're willing to reinstall the OS, in which case you should choose UEFI only.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia when does it ask to choose between UEFI or legacy when installing windows 10, I don't recall.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Oh, is it when you create a bootable usb?

Comment: No, actually how you boot the installer is how it installs, Windows or any modern Linux. The UEFI settings with UEFI only (or CSM/Legacy disabled) assure that the USB installer will necessarily boot in the UEFI mode.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia so after reinstalling windows in UEFI mode I would need to reformat all my other storage hdds?

Comment: Hopefully not. The system drive must be GPT for Windows in UEFI mode and so should be the NVME one. I think for the others it doesn't matter. But there are obvious advantages for GPT - performance and better partitions management - so, if starting from scratch in any modern system there's really no point in using the 40 years old MBR.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia sorry for late reply, but what is your opinion on this: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-convert-mbr-disk-gpt-move-bios-uefi-windows-10

Comment: I've heard of but never tried. I think at least once it was recommended by oldfred, an expert at AskUbuntu for a similar situation, in order to avoid reformatting the whole thing.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia probably the last question: if I created a windows 10 bootable usb with rufus using "gpt partition scheme for uefi computer" option the usb would boot in uefi mode regardless of the uefi settings correct? Sorry for asking so many questions, I'm just a bit confused and want to double check.

Comment: It should yes. But even with Legacy/CSM enabled what happens is the boot order showing 2 USBs, one with UEFI somewhere and the other without it. USBs made to boot only in one mode typically will not boot if the other is selected. Windows made with the official Media Creation tool can boot either way.